# Generate fake model predictions according to desired precision/recall values

Tags: python, numpy, model-evaluations

Lets assume I generate a random set of target labels for a binary classification with `N` elements and a certain frequency of the positive class (1), e.g. 10%:

```
targets =     [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
```

I now want to generate fake classification predictions such that the overall predictions roughly satisfy desired precision and recall values e.g. `precision = 0.8` and `recall = 0.2`. I don't need exact values but like to get close such as `0.78` and `0.25`.

```
predictions = [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...]
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently in python/numpy, ideally so that I can produce multiple sets of predictions by repeating the generation process with different random seeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can just calculate how many instances are needed for each classification status based on the constraints. For example:

- gold positive = 10%, i.e. $TP+FN=0.1 \times N$
- recall = 0.2, i.e. $TP/(TP+FN)=0.2$, so $FN=4\times TP$

From these two equations we get $TP=0.02 \times N$ and $FN=0.08 \times N$

- precision = 0.8, i.e. $TP/(TP+FP)=0.8$ so $FP=0.25\times TP = 0.005 \times N$
- Finally  $TP+FP+FN+TN=N$ so $TN=N-(TP+FP+FN)=0.895 \times N$

Let's say $N=1000$, we want to have 20 TP, 80 FN, 5 FP and 895 TN.

You should be able to write a code which does these calculations and then generates a list of predictions which match these constraints.

Note that technically this is not a model (not even a fake one) because there are no features and no real classification happening.